# Accidentally Dropped wp_usermeta

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I accidentally dropped my wp_usermeta database. I have't backed it up, since i made it just a few hours ago. How do I recover or make a new usermeta without starting all over?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's about system administration. You're probably out of luck, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't created any users yet (except of yourself as an admin and maybe some test user), you could quickly set up another wordpress installation with the same admin user data, then export the `wp_usermeta` table and import it into the other database (in phpadmin or whatever you use). When you are done, you can delete the new installation and its database.
Should work, I suppose...

Comment: Perfect. I made a test wp site yesterday that has a wp_usermeta.

Comment: did it work as intended?